# Getting error -Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in Selenium Maven project

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdrivermanager-java

I am using below code with WebDriverManager-

```
package MySelenium.mySelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class TestSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.demoqa.com");
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Getting below message when I run my program, although it's not impacting my execution. It ran successfully but with this message-

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23
```

I searched on stack overflow and found that if I add below two jars in POM.xml, error will be removed, so I have added these two jars but now started getting different message-

```
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
```

Message now getting-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23
```

Kindly help to remove these messages

Comment: I believe those are just a warning messages. Or is it causing any problem in launching chrome ?

Comment: yeah...they are just warning message. My test is running successfully. Chrome is launching perfectly. But what I can do to suppress these messages.

Comment: attached the logs in description itself. Kindly refer the last one

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below jars files

org.slf4j

slf4j-api

1.7.5

org.slf4j

slf4j-log4j12

1.7.5

Comment: As mentioned above, I have already added these two jars as well. Then start getting different warning message.(as shown above in description)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I am still getting slf4j warnings.